Translating a chess game from wikipedia to xskak, cheesboard
I would like to visualize the chessgame Zukertort – Blackburne, London 1883
, seen in the German wikipedia.
1/2) On Wikipedia they use the German names of the figures, so I set
\newskaklanguage{german}{KDTLSB}
\skaklanguage[german]
% König     K = K          King
% Dame     D <-->  Q   Queen    
% Turm      T  <---> R   Rook
% Läufer     L <-->  B   Bishop
% Springer  S <-->  N   Knight  
% Bauer      B <--> P    Pawn

2/2) On Wikipedia they use long notation, e.g. 1. c2–c4; instead of 1. c4.
Apparently xskak doesn't understand these (?).
So I started translating for the first moves:
1. c2–c4 
1. … e7–e6 2. e2–e3 Sg8–f6 3. Sg1–f3 b7–b6 4. Lf1–e2 
4. … Lc8–b7 5. 0–0 d7–d5 6. d2–d4 
6. … Lf8–d6 7. Sb1–c3 0–0 8. b2–b3 Sb8–d7 9. Lc1–b2 
9. … Dd8–e7 
10. Sc3–b5 Sf6–e4 11. Sb5xd6 c7xd6 12. Sf3–d2 Sd7–f6 
13. f2–f3 
... .... .... ... ... ... ... 

to
\mainline{%
1. c4  e7
2. e3 Sf6 
3. Sf3 b6 4. Le2 Lb7 5. 0–0 d5 
%6. d2–d4
}

But why does it crash at move No. 5?  Didn't I translate the cheesnotation correctly?

\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xskak}
\newskaklanguage{german}{KDTLSB}
\skaklanguage[german]
% König     K = K          King
% Dame     D <-->  Q   Queen    
% Turm      T  <---> R   Rook
% Läufer     L <-->  B   Bishop
% Springer  S <-->  N   Knight  
% Bauer      B <--> P    Pawn

\usepackage{chessboard}
\setchessboard{showmover=false, margin=false}

\begin{document}
\section*{Zukertort – Blackburne (London 1883)}
\newchessgame
\mainline{%
1. c4  e7
2. e3 Sf6 
3. Sf3 b6 4. Le2 Lb7 5. 0–0 d5 
%6. d2–d4
}

\noindent\xskakloop[step=1]{%%
\begin{tabular}{c}
\chessboard[tinyboard,
setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]
\\
\xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{lan}\rule{0pt}{5mm} \\[0.5em]%
\end{tabular}\hspace{4mm}}%%
\end{document}


Castling should be denoted as O-O instead of 0-0.

With the tip in comments, I was able to solve it:

\documentclass[]{article}

\usepackage{xskak}
\usepackage{chessboard}

%\usepackage[LSBC3,T1]{fontenc}
%\setboardfontencoding{LSBC3}

% Deutsche Figurenkürzel ====================
\newskaklanguage{german}{KDTLSB}
\skaklanguage[german]
% König     K = K          King
% Dame     D <-->  Q   Queen    
% Turm      T  <---> R   Rook
% Läufer     L <-->  B   Bishop
% Springer  S <-->  N   Knight  
% Bauer      B <--> P    Pawn
% ===================================


\setchessboard{showmover=false, margin=false}
%
\storechessboardstyle{mystyle}{
% boardfontencoding=LSBC3,
tinyboard,% board size
 pgfstyle=color,
 color=brown!88,% black fields
 trimtocolor=black,
 backboard,
 trimtocolor=white,
 color=brown!33,% white fields
 backboard,
setfontcolors,
}
\setchessboard{style=mystyle}% activate style globally

\begin{document}
%\section{Start}
%\newchessgame
%\chessboard[tinyboard, style=mystyle]

\section*{Zukertort – Blackburne (London 1883)}
\newchessgame
\mainline{
1. c2c4  e7e6 % Züge ohne Trennstrich c2c4 notieren (nicht c2-c4)
2. e2e3 Sg8f6 
3. Sg1f3 b7b6 
4. Lf1e2 Lc8b7 
5. O-O d7d5 % kleine Rochade als O-O (nicht 0-0) eingeben!
6. d2d4 Lf8d6 
7. Sb1c3 O-O %siehe oben
8. b2b3 Sb8d7 
9. Lc1b2 Dd8e7 
10. Sc3b5 Sf6e4 
11. Sb5xd6 c7xd6 
12. Sf3d2 Sd7f6 
13. f2f3 Se4xd2 
14. Dd1xd2 d5xc4?!
15. Le2xc4 d6d5 
16. Lc4d3 Tf8c8
17. Ta1e1 Tc8c7?!   
18. e3e4 Ta8c8
19. e4e5 Sf6e8
20. f3f4 g7g6
21. Te1e3!   f7f5
22. e5xf6!\,e.p.  Se8xf6 % e.p. ohne Leerstelle oder Leerstelle manuell setzen '\,' 
23. f4f5!  Sf6e4 
24. Ld3xe4 d5xe4
25. f5xg6! Tc7c2
26. g6xh7+ Kg8h8
27. d4d5+ e6e5
28. Dd2b4!   Tc8c5
29. Tf1f8+   Kh8xh7
30. Db4xe4+ Kh7g7 
31. Lb2xe5+  Kg7xf8
32. Le5g7+!  Kf8g8 
33. De4xe7
}

\noindent\xskakloop[step=1]{%%
\begin{tabular}{c}
\chessboard[tinyboard,
setfen=\xskakget{nextfen}]
\\
\xskakget{opennr}\xskakget{lan}%
\rule{0pt}{5mm} \\[0.5em]%
\end{tabular}\hspace{4mm}}%%
\end{document}

